# WordPress Admin dashboard is not displayed properly

Tags: wordpress

[image: Admin login is not diplay properly]

[image: dashboard is not display properly]

I tried to deactivate all the plugin but still problem is occure.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Try a different theme, might be theme issue

Comment: See in your browser console if there are any errors? If nothing, check in your server's PHP error log and mysql error log. Usually gives some indication of error.

Comment: when i am trying to access site.it's working fine

Comment: share your website URL

Comment: Did you move the wp-admin to a different location or did you change the permissions for security reasons?

Answer (score 4):

finally got the solution..add below line in wp-config.php

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

now dashboard display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at console of browser.  Maybe you can see what is causing error there

Comment: Try to delete cache and cookies.

Comment: Have u check a log file? Maybe you can find clues there